# Android hindi chars soft keypad?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

I am using Hindi fonts in my application by using the following code as:

```
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "fonts/DroidHindi.ttf");
txt.setTypeface(font);
```

Now I wanted to take input from the user in an edit Text box in hindi language..So for this, Hindi soft keypad is required , can anyone pls guide me how to add hindi language soft keypad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends entirely on the user's choice of keyboard.

To test Hindi input, download one of the Hindi IME available on the market, such as PaniniKeypad Hindi IME, or get GO Keyboard and "Hindi for GO Keyboard", all of them available on the Android Market for free.

Comment: thanks alot..I have downloaded Hindi for Go keyboard..and now how can I use it my application to take input from user in hindi chars??

Comment: Short answer: Long-press any text field and select Go Keyboard. Follow the instructions here: http://www.androidguys.com/2011/03/07/android-1-change-keyboard/

Comment: Firstly thanks alot for your reply..and its working now my application shows me hindi soft keypad ..but its not taking hindi chars as inpt..It still shows me the square boxes when I am typing a characters..

Comment: Its not fare, how can we say to client that download first Hindi IME.

How to integrate that in our application.